# Excel: SUM of SUMIF vs SUM of VLOOKUP with Array Function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is Microsoft Excel for Mac.

I'm trying to make a Nutrition Data worksheet as shown in the screenshot. The idea is to take the list of foods entered (B6:B7), look up those foods in the list of foods available (B2:B4), and sum the calories of the entered foods from the data about the food available (C2:C4).

Since the list of foods entered can be of arbitrary length, I need an array function. I need to look up the Calories value for each food entered, and sum those values.

My question is about the difference between these two functions:

```
={VLOOKUP(B7:B8,B1:C4,2)}
={SUMIF(B2:B4,B7:B8,C2:C4)}
```

Both of these return the same values, as you can see in the spreadsheet. They each return 100 if you put the result in a single cell. They return {100, 200} if you put the result in 2 cells. This is what I would expect. The VLOOKUP is looking up each of B7 and B8 in the table and getting the calorie value (100 and 200), whereas the SUMIF is summing values in C2:C4 if B2:B4 match each of B7 and B8, which results in 100 and 200.

The difference comes about when you try to sum these result. Using either SUM or SUMPRODUCT of the SUMIF result, you get a result of 300. However, doing the same with the VLOOKUP result, you get a result of 100. I could see either 300 or 100 making sense. That is, 300 would make sense if the SUM or SUMPRODUCT was being applied to the array, whereas 100 would make sense if the SUM or SUMPRODUCT was applied to each element of the array separately and a total sum was never taken. However, I don't see why the two are different when applied to the intermediate results of VLOOKUP and SUMIF.

[image: Nutrition Worksheet]

Comment: I'd suggest going with the one that's gives you the correct answer. ;)

Comment: Don't you want to know about the deeper mysteries of Array Functions in Excel?